# redux-form field is not giving the onChange() e value in callback

Tags: redux, redux-form

redux-form field is not giving the onChange() e value in callback.

```
<Field
 onChange={(e)=>{console.log(e)}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Field
 onChange={(e, x)=>{console.log(x)}}
/>
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/field.md/#-code-onchange-event-newvalue-previousvalue-name-gt-void-code-optional-), the signature of onChange function is:

`onChange : (event, newValue, previousValue)`

That means that the value of the `Field` is passed as second argument to the function, so you should change your code to:

`onChange={(e, value) => { console.log(value); } }`